# How to implement drag and drop on RecyclerView for different item types?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I want to implement RecyclerView with the following structure:
There are devices and locations. Each location can contain several devices.
Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I want to add an ability to drag and drop devices changing their locations. So you will be able to drag and drop qr1 device to "Kharkiv" location. And Kharkiv location will contain qr8 and qr1. And Kiev location will be deleted(cause it will have no devices). I tried this sample https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.qfr9nfkkl But when I drag qr1 to Kharkiv location qr1 simply swaps with qr8.